# Xamarin connectivity change transform function

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin. I would like to change this function:

```
 public void CheckWifiContinuously()
 {
        CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Conn = args.IsConnected ? true : false;
        };
 }
```

into a function that returns `args.IsConnected` (a boolean)

I take the code from [here](https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-continuously-check-internet-connection-in-xamarin-forms/).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) and specifically [Connectivity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=android) as CrossConnectivity features have been consolidated into Xamarin.Essentials toolkit.

```
private bool CheckInternet()
        {
            var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: Visual studio cannot find the package

Comment: @kikis you must download it through nuget in order to use it in your solution. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/

Answer (score 1):

The code which you have used is to track the network state changed event. What you want to achieve is "How to check if Network is available or not". You can do this by following:

```
if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    //Connected
}
else
{
  //Not Connected
}
```

You actually not need to create a separate function. You can use this property directly as I mentioned above.
Hope this helps!